# Discord Embed made my code stop working? What is happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to fix this error for hours now, but I can't find out why it's happening. It doesn't even send the error message added to the code. When I try to use the command, it sends nothing in chat, and just spams the console with errors. It did all of this when I added the error embed. Here's my code:

````
        if(!message.author.bot) {
          if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Mod")){
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();
            if (user) {
              const member = message.guild.member(user);
              if (member) {
                member
                let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
                if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
                let successkick = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  successkick.setTitle("SUCCESS")
                  successkick.setColor('GREEN')
                  successkick.setFooter('http://kroxbotweb.deflowo.repl.co/kick.html')
                  successkick.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                  successkick.setDescription(`${member} has been successfully kicked from the server. \n Reason: ${reason}`);
                let errormsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  errormsg.setTitle('ERROR')
                  errormsg.setColor('RED')
                  errormsg.setFooter('http://kroxbotweb.deflowo.repl.co/kick.html') 
                  errormsg.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL()) 
                  errormsg.setDescription(`**An error has occurred.** \n **1.** Does this user have higher permissions than me? \n **2.** Did you ping the user? \n **3.** Do they have server permissions? \n \n Targetted user: ${member}`)
                try {
                  member.kick(reason)
                } catch (err) {
                  message.channel.send(errormsg)
                  return
                }
              } else {
                message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
              }
            } else {
              message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
            }
          } else {
            message.reply("You need a role named Admin/Mod to do this!")
          }
        } else {
          message.channel.send("Nice try.")
        }
        break;```
````

Comment: please help me, i still dont know whats going on

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was actually that I forgot to put `await` in try. What it should have looked like is put below. I noticed how with await it worked fine, but without it stopped working strangely. The code was skipping the try and telling me it worked, even though it didn't. I think `await` stops the code from going forward until it is finished. I hope this helps other people. :)

```
          if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Mod")){
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();
            if (user) {
              const member = message.guild.member(user);
              if (member) {
                member
                let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
                if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
                let successkick = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  successkick.setTitle("SUCCESS")
                  successkick.setColor('GREEN')
                  successkick.setFooter('http://kroxbotweb.deflowo.repl.co/kick.html')
                  successkick.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                  successkick.setDescription(`${member} has been successfully kicked from the server. \n Reason: ${reason}`);
                let errormsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  errormsg.setTitle('ERROR')
                  errormsg.setColor('RED')
                  errormsg.setFooter('http://kroxbotweb.deflowo.repl.co/kick.html') 
                  errormsg.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL()) 
                  errormsg.setDescription(`**An error has occurred.** \n **1.** Does this user have higher permissions than me? \n **2.** Did you ping the user? \n **3.** Do they have server permissions? \n \n Targetted user: ${member}`)
                try {
                  await member.kick(reason)
                } catch (err) {
                  message.channel.send(errormsg)
                  return
                }
              } else {
                message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
              }
            } else {
              message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
            }
          } else {
            message.reply("You need a role named Admin/Mod to do this!")
          }
        } else {
          message.channel.send("Nice try.")
        }
        break;
```